# pyspark - read csv with custom row delimiter

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delimiter

how can I read a csv file with custom row delimiter (\x03) using pyspark?
I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
df = spark.read.option("lineSep","\x03").csv(path)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine with both OSS Spark (3.2.0) and DBR 9.1 ML:

```py
>>> df = spark.read.option("lineSep","\x03")\
     .option("header", "true").csv("/path_to_file.csv")
>>> df.show()
+----+----+
|val1|val2|
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
|   3|   4|
+----+----+
```

Look for problems inside file, or something like this.